# Tens changed with a coin deposit (8 letters)

Tags: cryptic-clues

Cryptic puzzle. Chosen Letters of Synonyms of words in question interchanged to get solution.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: Why do you have "Chosen Letters of Synonyms of words in question interchanged to get solution" in your question? It rather defeats the skill required to solve cryptic clues.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go with

> [**sediment**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sediment), which is a deposit formed by mixing (changing) the letters of "Tens" and putting "dime" (a coin) in the middle.

For exchanging one-shot cryptic clues, the [Sphinx's lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) has an ongoing "Cryptic Clue Chat Chains" thing, where you solve the previous puzzle, and then post your own.

Comment: Aaaah, so that's what that CCCC is all about...